# Animated GIF: Reverse animation and append it to the end of the animation

Tags: imagemagick, reverse, animated-gif

Given an animated image in the GIF format,

How can I add the reversed order of frames to the end of the animation?

Answer (score 3):

See [Patrol Cycles](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#patrol) in the ImageMagick documentation:

> To add a reversed order of frames to the end of the animation, so the resulting animation cycles between the first and last frames of the original animation. It's a bit like a guard walking a patrol between two points, and is called a 'Patrol Cycle'.

```
convert input.gif -coalesce -duplicate 1,-2-1 -quiet -layers OptimizePlus -loop 0 patrol_cycle.gif
```